# Boolean != false

Tags: java, boolean, autoboxing

In Java, you would usually say that

`if(someBool != false)`

is the same as

`if(someBool)`

But what if `someBool` is not of type `boolean` but  `Boolean`, and its value is `null`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out yourself?

Comment: @Jesper: I did, see my own answer below

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It will throw a `NullPointerException` ([autounboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) of `null` throws NPE).

But that only means that you must not allow a `null` value. Either use a default, or don't use autounboxing and make a non-null check. Because using a `null` value of a boolean means you have 3, not 2 values. (Better ways of handling it were proposed by Michael and Tobiask)

Answer (score 127):

If you want to handle `Boolean` instances as well as primitives and be null-safe, you can use this:

```
if(Boolean.TRUE.equals(someBool))
```

Comment: Or if you want to do something when someBool is `null` as well, `!Boolean.FALSE.equals(someBool)`

Comment: @Bart `Boolean.FALSE.equals(null)` will return `false` - your statement does exactly the same as Michael's answer.

Comment: @Jesper: Nope. `!Boolean.FALSE.equals(null)` returns `true` while `Boolean.TRUE.equals(null)` returns `false`. However, this does demonstrate nicely that double negations are hard to parse mentally and therefore are better avoided.

Comment: In my case I have a Boolean doFoo. An error is thrown if doFoo is true and foo is not done, or if doFoo is false and foo is done. If doFoo is null no errors are thrown regardless

Comment: @Michael, @Bart Argh, you're right, I even tried it out but made a mistake while doing so... sorry.

Answer (score 20):

Use ApacheCommons BooleanUtils.isTrue() or .isFalse()

Comment: This is a great way to go.  The ApacheCommons libraries make Java programming a joy.

Comment: glancing at the code in lang3, this does `Boolean.TRUE.equals(...)`, etc. Personally didn't think it was worth the 3rd party dep.

Comment: @xenoterracide not if you just want to avoid `Boolean.TRUE.equals(myValue)` but if you're already using the Apache Commons library for other stuff, then why not take advantage of it even more?

Answer (score 4):

If `someBool` is `Boolean`

```
if (someBull != null && someBull) {
  //Yeah, true.
}
```

Since Boolean can be `null` make sure you avoid `NullPointerException` by checking for not null.

Answer (score 3):

I did a little test:

```
    Boolean o = null;
    try {
        System.out.println(o ? "yes" : "no");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        System.out.println((o != false) ? "yes" : "no");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The output is surprising:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at btest.main(btest.java:10)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at btest.main(btest.java:15)
```

The first NPE is to be expected, because o will be autounboxed (and that fails because it's null). The second happens for the same reason, but it doesn't feel natural. Anyway, the solution is to do:

```
System.out.println(!Boolean.FALSE.equals(o) ? "yes" : "no");
```

Comment: You can avoid the double negation by saying `Boolean.TRUE.equals(o)`

Comment: @ChrisParton no, you can not actualy. See the comments on Michael Borgwardt answer for difference in null case

Answer (score 1):

You can however compare a null Boolean with a Boolean instance. For example :

```
Boolean myBool = null;
System.out.println(myBool == Boolean.FALSE);
System.out.println(myBool == Boolean.TRUE);
```

prints :

```
false
false
```

Comment: This won't work if I create a Boolean with new, it will work only when [valueOf](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.valueOf%28int%29) and possibly autoboxing is used `assertThat(new Boolean(true) == Boolean.TRUE, is(true));` this test doesn't pass...

Comment: @stivlo: I would have though Booleans (and all primitive-representing objects) would have been in some form of pool and considered equals. Thank you for the comment, I learnt something today.

Comment: use `Boolean.TRUE.equals(myBool)` or `Boolean.FALSE.equals(myBool)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Good illustrations of the difference between the primitive **boolean** & the object **Boolean**. The former can be only **true** or **false**. The latter can be **true**, **false**, or **unknown/undefined**. (i.e., null). Which you use depends on whether you want to deal with two use cases or three.

Comment: Unfortunately there are other reasons one would want to use Boolean, for instance storing the values a collection of Objects.  In that case you have to deal with the three use cases whether you want them or not.

Answer (score 0):

It's old, but `Boolean.valueOf(null)` is `false`, just like `Boolean.valueOf(false)` is `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Boolean constructor accepts null, returns FALSE and doesn't throw a NullPointerTantrum.

```
 new Boolean(null);
 <false>
```

This has the added bonus of also giving a thruthy response to the string `"true"` which is not the case for `Boolean.TRUE.equals` but we are more restricted again having only constructors for Strings and Booleans.

Something you can overcome with string concatenation, which is also null-proof.

```
 new Boolean(""+null);
 <false>

 new Boolean(""+false);
 <false>

 new Boolean(""+new Object());
 <false>

 new Boolean(""+6);
 <false>

 new Boolean(""+new Integer(9));
 <false>
```

Ensuring that all the TRUE options, available in java, still remains.

```
 new Boolean(""+true);
 <true>

 new Boolean(""+"true");
 <true>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's Java 7+ you can use

```
import java.util.Objects;
```

And

```
if (Objects.equals(someBool, true))
```

Answer (score -1):

As Boolean will give you an object, you must always check for NULL before working on the object

Answer (score -2):

If its null then you'll get a NullPointerException